# Inject ILogger<T> into an Abstract Class

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, abstract-class, deep-copy

As part of solving a different problem, I started toying with creating an abstract class to contain DeepCopy functionality to solve said problem.

As part of my DeepCopy, I want to report anything that goes wrong.

However, I am finding it more troublesome than not simply implementing the ILogger as I would a Repository or Service.

An example of implementation:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace OrchardCore.A.B{
    public abstract class DeepCopyService<T> {
        private readonly ILogger<DeepCopyService<T>> _logger;

        public DeepCopyService(ILogger<DeepCopyService<T>> logger) {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a copy of the current object which has no direct reference in memory. The return value is a completely separate object.
        /// </summary>
        public T DeepCopy() {
            if (this == null) return default(T);

            try {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new JsonSerializerSettings {
                    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
                });

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "There was an issue trying to DeepCopy the value: {obj}", this);
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I am finding in the research I did before coming here, I am learning more and more that what I am trying is just not meant to be.

Classes that use this `DeepCopyService` will start demanding a constructor that takes in `ILogger<DeepCopyService<T>>`.

My use case is a dumb object that records a data structure for an organization. I want to cache this data before running it through a filter depending on the current access of the user viewing it. The problem I solved was the value cached was being modified, as when the information was loaded from the cache, it was by reference and thus being changed by the filter. So the organization gets deep copied before filtered to break the reference.

```
Org org = new Org();
Filter(org.DeepCopy());
```

I don't want to have to pass in `_logger` into every use of `Org`. And even if I was willing to, the repo the object is defined in has `ILogger<OrgRepository>`, not `ILogger<DeepCopyService<T>>`.

This is where I feel it isn't meant to be. However, I also find it odd that I wouldn't be able to log issues from an abstract given the abstract could be doing other things that especially require error logging.

Maybe I am thinking about it wrong. But I ask now that perhaps I am attempting to solve this problem the wrong way, or missing another simple implementation because of a tunnel focus on the DI model at the moment.

Comment: `I don't want to have to pass in _logger into every use of Org.` you have to. In fact, you have to create `Org` through DI if you want services to be injected into it. Your `Org` *is a* `DeepCopyService` so it does need an ILogger. If you construct `Org` through DI, the DI itself will add the `ILogger` instance and give you back a ready-to-use object. If you don't use DI, you'll have to provide the logger in the constructor.

Comment: BTW this goes beyond logging and DI. When you have a class with a non-default constructor, derived classes should provide the arguments. When the argument is an external type, the derived classes should either construct that type, find it eg in a static location or ask for it through their own constructor

Comment: Org(anization) sound more like a data thing and at best shouldn't have any dependency. Why you create a generic baseclass when a simple service (presumably singelton)  should be sufficient. That can have a generic copy method like `T Copy<T>(T object)`.

Comment: Not even a service - an extension method. Besides, the `catch` block is a bug in itself because it hides exceptions. That's an ugly bug. The calling code will have no idea what went wrong. Testing and debugging code that uses this will be really hard

Answer (score 9):

If you have a constructor in an abstract class, then you have no choice but to use it in any class that is derived from it. For `ILogger` specifically, though, you make your abstract class use the non-generic version of `ILogger` which allows derived classes to use more specific implementations of the logger since [`ILogger<T>` implements `ILogger`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/ILoggerOfT.cs#L14)

```
public abstract class DeepCopyService<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public DeepCopyService(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

And your derived class would look like this:

```
public class DerivedClass : DeepCopyService<Foo>
{
    public DeepCopyService(ILogger<DerivedClass> logger)
        : base(logger)
    {
    }
}
```

You may also want to make the `_logger` `protected` so you can use it in derived classes too.

Also, your example code manually `new`s up the `Org` object, but you should really be doing that with dependency injection.

Comment: I believe the DeepCopyService constructor should be declared protected.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the fact that `DeepCopy` just swallows exceptions is a quite confusing, I think other developers would not expect such behaviour, I would suggest using `bool TryDeepCopy<T>(out T t)` approach.

As for the issue itself - since you want to instantiate objects via constructor (`Org org = new Org();`) and not via the DI - I suggest to separate the concerns , the abstract base class will implement `DeepCopy` which throws (abstracted via interface) and some service which will do the rest:

```cs
public interface IDeepCopyable<T>
{
    T DeepCopy();
}

public abstract class DeepCopyable<T> : IDeepCopyable<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a copy of the current object which has no direct reference in memory. The return value is a completely separate object.
    /// </summary>
    public T DeepCopy()
    {
        if (this == null) return default(T);

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
        });

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}

public interface IDeepCopyService<T> where T : IDeepCopyable<T>
{
    bool TryDeepCopy(T? toCopy, out T? t);
}

public class DeepCopyService<T> : IDeepCopyService<T> where T : IDeepCopyable<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger<DeepCopyService<T>> _logger;

    public DeepCopyService(ILogger<DeepCopyService<T>> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public bool TryDeepCopy(T? toCopy, out T? t)
    {
        t =  default;
        if (toCopy == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        try
        {
            t = toCopy.DeepCopy();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Standard DI supports registering open generics, so usage can look like:

```cs
class Impl: DeepCopyable<Impl>
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IDeepCopyService<>), typeof(DeepCopyService<>));
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var dcs = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDeepCopyService<Impl>>();
var original = new Impl();
if (dcs.TryDeepCopy(original, out var copied))
{
    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(original, copied)); //prints False
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are kind of going a bit against dependency injection flow.

You want object to perform an operation and for operation to be logged. Logging does not belong to object responsibilities therefore it's delegated to an external object (abstracted via interface) making it a dependency of your object.

So your object has to somehow obtain reference to your object -> and the most valid scenario is injecting such reference via constructor.

Here is the real catch you are explicitly creating this object yourself using the new operation therefore you're not really doing any DI here because container is not responsible for object creation - you are, therefore you are responsible for providing it with it's dependencies.

The situation would change if the Org object would be injected itself (making DI Container responsible for it's creation but than I highly doubt that constructor parameter would be a problem).

In theory you could try using a service locator antipattern but you've been warned.